# Tidy Converting <Span Style="Font-Style:Bold"> to <Class="C1">

Tags: php, tidy

I am using the PHP 5 Tidy class to format html.

Everything is fine except when it gets passed a style attribute, when it changes it into a class attribute. As I am only formatting the body of a document, not the head, there is no class defined in the head for the attribute to read.

I have looked through all the Tidy  options but can't work out how to stop this behaviour.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try switching the [clean](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html#clean) option off.